# merge several class into one single class

Tags: css, sass, stylesheet

I want to create some kind of class (.masterClass) that it is build with three other classes (.classX, .classY, classZ)

I'm using SASS and tried to use the @extend withe the following code:

```
.masterClass{
@extend .classX;
@extend .classY;
@extend .classZ;
}
```

and the result is:

```
.classX, .masterClass{....}

.classY, .masterClass{....}

.classZ, .masterClass{....}
```

All I want is one .masterClass with all properties from all the other classes.

I know that in my HTML element I can call all the three classes, but for this project in particular i must have just one class.

Is this possible ?? How can I accomplish that?

Thanks

Comment: But why does it matter? You can still use `.masterClass` in your HTML and it will work..won't it? http://sassmeister.com/gist/50de438f79b7694f64e6

Comment: @Paulie_D  It generates three .masterClasses and the browser only reads the last one. Or am I wrong?